# How to access the inbuilt video player of the android phone programatically

Tags: android, video

Whenever we play a normal video through phone or sdcard in android's phone memory, it opens with the inbuilt video player. In my program, I want to play my application's videos through the inbuilt video player. For this I need to access the inbuilt video player. Is there any API to access the video player? I know that we have the VideoView. But it does not have start, stop, pause, forward or rewind button which can be at the best provided by the inbuilt video player. Please provide me a solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an `ACTION_VIEW` `Intent`, with a `Uri` pointing to your video, with the appropriate MIME type, and call `startActivity()` with that `Intent`.

Comment: i try this code  movieUrl = "android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.raw.twobaby;Intent tostart = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
     tostart.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(movieUrl),"video/3gp");
       startActivity(tostart); but come error. please help me.